# RDP to ubuntu server?

Tags: 14.04, server

I have a Ubuntu 14.04 Server and I want to be able to RDP to it with Ubuntu desktop 14.04 installed on it. How do I set up the desktop version of ubuntu in terminal? I tried xrdp but it's not the GUI I want, I want the 14.04 version of the Ubuntu Desktop?

Answer (score 0):

You can access your server by the VNC protocol. Immediate access by RDP in a manner like you access windows desktops from windows desktops is not possible.

## Share your desktop

In the Dash, open Desktop Sharing.

To let others view your desktop, select Allow other users to view your desktop. This means that other people will be able to attempt to connect to your computer and view what's on your screen.

To let others interact with your desktop, select Allow other users to control your desktop. This may allow the other person to move your mouse, run applications, and browse files on your computer, depending on the security settings which you are currently using.

## Security

It is important that you consider the full extent of what each security option means before changing it.

### Confirm access to your machine

If you want to be able to choose whether to allow someone to access your desktop, select You must confirm each access to this machine. If you disable this option, you will not be asked whether you want to allow someone to connect to your computer.

### Enable password

To require other people to use a password when connecting to your desktop, select Require the user to enter this password. If you do not use this option, anyone can attempt to view your desktop.

**This option is disabled by default, but you should enable it and set a secure password.**

### Allow access to your desktop over the Internet

If your router supports UPnP Internet Gateway Device Protocol and it is enabled, you can allow other people who are not on your local network to view your desktop. To allow this, select Automatically configure UPnP router to open and forward ports. Alternatively, you can configure your router manually.

## Problems with encryption

When you try to view your desktop from Windows with i.e. TightVNC you may get failure messages about there is no supported encryption available. You may deactivate encryption on your server by:

Open a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and type:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.Vino require-encryption false
```

Then hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

This will disable the requirement of an encrypted connection.

Comment: My server is just the server version not the desktop version, I need to install the desktop and then RDP into it..

Comment: Then you should use a combination of ssh and Xpra - that works very well on my servers